# How to bind cmd shell in Ncat(Not netcat) in windows?

Tags: shell, cmd

How can i bind a shell(cmd) using Ncat.
I want to do that there should be Ncat work like telnet server. It should listen on specific port.
And as I connect with that there should be persistent connection made.
(AS we do in telnet server and client exact same. Of course no need to username and password).

**Example:** Server: ncat 192.xxx.xxx.xxx listen on specific port

now i connect this server with my client (telnet client or Ncat as a client).
I just want to send any dos command(internal or external), that should be executed on server and send the result back to my client.

(Sorry for my bad English)
(I want to use Nmap Ncat not netcat).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a blatant security hole, since this allows a totally unauthenticated user access to a shell on your machine, but you can do:

```
ncat -k -e /bin/sh -l $PORT
```

Replace /bin/sh with the appropriate command for your situation.

ncat has --ssl* options to provide authentication, and it would be wise to consider them.

Comment: Be very careful.  If you are running exactly the command given in this solution, then you have a gaping security hole.  Of course, you mention that your running windows, so this is redundant.  But redundancy is good.  :)

Comment: Yes you are right i consider for ssh option. One more thing if i want to start ncat in stealth mode means no gui should be shown. then how can i do this. i tried to make a batch file and insert the command for ncat, and after that i tried to make exe with no gui mode using Bat to Exe Converter but it is still showing the GUI window. So how will i achieve this.